# php joomla template (how-to?) the proper way

Tags: php, joomla, templating

Greetings all,

I just wanted to know what is the proper way to do template's in Joomla?
If i have four boxes in footer (4 columns) how can i automate them in the template so their content inside can be managed from the back-end?

So far, i have seen custom html block modules and using those. But wouldn't it be funny if there are loads of such blocks and than managing them from modules individually?

Now suppose if i have a slogan/tag line for my website; and i want it to be managed from backend.. Do i need to create that custom block even for such single line?

May be i am going to wrong direction. Can someone guide me please?

Regards,
Jhon.

Answer (score 0):

A Joomla template is simply a map the outlines the various positions that available to put modules in. These positions are built around the component display area. You can load basically anything you want in to a module position. You will probably need to download some modules from the Joomla Extension Directory, there are tons of options.

The Custom HTML module is appropriate for simple content that is not going to change very often. This would be good for a company tag line that doesn't ever change. There are various modules that would allow you to load content from the latest Joomla articles based on section or category. There are modules for login forms, stock prices, RSS feeds, weather, all kinds of stuff.